# How do I interpret merge-with that takes a fn in clojure?

Tags: clojure, backend

I'm currently learning Clojure and I'm a total beginner and I would appreciate some help understanding. I went through some code today and found this.

```
(let [timepoints (merge-with (fn [mf swt] [mf swt]) timepoint-max timepoint-sum )])
```

where `mf, swt, timepoint-max and timepoint-sum` looks something like

```
{"Timepoint1": 3, "Timepoint2": 2}
```

So what does the code above do?

I understand that we set the variable `timepoints` to be some sort of union between the two maps(?). But I'm especially confused about the `fn [mf swt] [mf swt]` part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `(fn [mf swt] [mf swt])` is an anonymous clojure function that constructs a vector from the two arguments passed into it, e.g

```clj
((fn [mf swt] [mf swt]) :a :b)
;; => [:a :b]
```

The expression `(merge-with (fn [mf swt] [mf swt]) timepoint-max timepoint-sum )` is a call to the function [merge-with](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge-with) with first argument `(fn [mf swt] [mf swt])`, second argument `timepoint-max` and third argument `timepoint-sum`. Here is an example where we bind `timepoint-max` and `timepoint-sum` to some example values:

```clj
(def timepoint-max {:x 0 :y 1})
(def timepoint-sum {:y 100 :z 200})

(merge-with (fn [mf swt] [mf swt]) timepoint-max timepoint-sum)
;; => {:x 0, :y [1 100], :z 200}
```

Read the docs of [merge-with](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge-with) to understand what it does:

> Returns a map that consists of the rest of the maps conj-ed onto the
> first.  If a key occurs in more than one map, the mapping(s) from the
> latter (left-to-right) will be combined with the mapping in the result
> by calling (f val-in-result val-in-latter).

In the above example, what we actually compute is the same as

```clj
{:x (:x timepoint-max)
 :y ((fn [mf swt] [mf swt]) (:y timepoint-max) (:y timepoint-sum))
 :z (:z timepoint-sum)}
;; => {:x 0, :y [1 100], :z 200}
```

where the function `(fn [mf swt] [mf swt])` is used to combine the two values at the only overlapping key `:y`.

The full expression `(let [timepoints (merge-with (fn [mf swt] [mf swt]) timepoint-max timepoint-sum )])` is a [let](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let) form that binds values to symbols but it is not very useful because its `*exprs` part is empty, so it always evaluates to `nil`:

```clj
(let [timepoints (merge-with (fn [mf swt] [mf swt]) timepoint-max timepoint-sum )])
;; => nil
```

In order for it to evaluate to something else, e.g. `timepoints`, it would have to be modified to something like

```clj
(let [timepoints (merge-with (fn [mf swt] [mf swt]) timepoint-max timepoint-sum) ] 
  timepoints)
;; => {:x 0, :y [1 100], :z 200}
```

Comment: Note that `(fn [mf swt] [mf swt])` is just `clojure.core/vector` or just `vector`.